# Value of static variable in native library between calls from managed library

Tags: c#, c++, iis, web-applications, dllexport

I have managed web application (WCF service running from IIS, FWIW) written in c#. In certain situations, it performs calls to functions from unmanaged c/c++ library. 
Inside the unmanaged library I have some global static variable. 
I see that some of the times the value of this variable changes to its initial value between the calls while I would expect it to keep its value always.
The structure is something like this:

Managed.cs

```
        public class Managed
        {
            [DllImport("native.dll", EntryPoint = "?MyFunc@@YGXXZ", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            static extern void MyFunc();
            public void MyWrapper()
            {
                  MyFunc();
            }
        }

    }
```

Native.cpp

```
    static int counter = -1;
     __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall  MyFunc()
    {
         counter++; // sometimes when I enter this function the counter drops to -1
    }
```

My question is:  Does it work as supposed to? Am I missing something? How can I "remember" the value of the variable between the calls?

EDIT: Actually I have 2 web applications running in the same application pool in IIS. So it looks like these 2 applications while running in the same IIS working process, each one loads different instance of my DLL. So the static variables in these two instances are unrelated. Now my (updated) question is: how can I make these 2 applications share the instance of native DLL? And also - how can it be that the same worker process has 2 copies of DLL loaded simultaneously?

Comment: Are all calls coming from the same thread?

Comment: Generally not. But the calls to MyWrapper are inside lock, so I can be sure that there is no concurrency. Also , I checked this on test server with me as the only caller, and the behavior is the same.

Comment: So it seems that the native DLL is being unloaded between calls? Can you confirm that with some debugging in DllMain?

Comment: It is not unloaded.. In a debugger output window I see the message "Unloaded native.dll " only when the process exits.Also now I see that it's inconsistent - sometimes I do see the changed value. (added to OP)

Comment: Sounds confusing. If it's all in the same process, it shouldn't reinitialise the statics, and if you have threads synchronised it should remain consistent. Will have to think.....

Comment: @Roger-Rowland - thanks for the idea of debugging in DllMain. Now I can see that I get to it all the time with ul_reason_for_call of DLL_THREAD_ATTACH and DLL_THREAD_DETACH - even when my web service is inactive. I think this is normal - since IIS keeps creating and destroying threads. What is definitely unexpected is that I get to DllMain with different values of hModule parameter -  meaning that I have multiple instances of my dll (I saw at least 2). This explains, of course, the "reinitializing" of static variable. So now - why do I have many instances of dll? Can I make it singleton?

Comment: You should only have multiple instances if they are in different processes. If you can `OutputDebugString` to trace when you get calls to DllMain with DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, maybe you can see for sure if there are multiple processes. You can only debug one process at a time I guess. I don't know details of P/Invoke but may be worth separating calls into a new AppDomain.

Comment: I attach the debugger to one process only - that's for sure. So how can it be connected to multiple processes? And I definitely see different values, while debugging the same process.

Comment: That's why I suggested `OutputDebugString`. If you use [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx), you can see the output from any process that hits that line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97287/discussion-between-grisha-and-roger-rowland).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that the problem was with multiple web applications running from the same application pool. Though IIS uses the same working process for all of the applications, it looks like somehow it creates different copies of unmanaged dlls for each application with different handles and different sets of static variables. That's why they were re-initialized.